# Permission denied when try to write-open a c code file in perl script

Tags: perl, permissions, notepad++

I got an error of  Permission denied when try to write-open a c code file in perl script. but if I try to read-open the c code file, it works. I check my permission with right clicking the  c file and then properties-security, see that I have both read and write permission. What`s more strange is that if I open the c file in notepad, I can read and write to it, but when I use notepad++, it does not work, it just can read, not write.

Thanks in advance.
help~~

Err.. you are right, it´s read only, seems that it´s a stupid question...anyway, thank you for all your help, nice day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the file may be locked by a process.  You can use [Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653) to determine which process, if any, is locking the file.

Choose `Find -> Find Handle or DLL...` and search for the file name.

Comment: hi, I try it, but nothing shows which means there is no process handling it.  other suggestion?

Comment: Well, I've never tried it, but you could try [Unlocker](http://download.cnet.com/Unlocker/3000-2248_4-10493998.html) and see if that can unlock the file.  I'm not sure why Process Explorer wouldn't be seeing it, but it does sound locked.  Can the file be moved/copied/deleted?

Comment: yes, it can be deleted and moved. And I can use notepad to modify it but using notepad++, I can just read it, but can´t modify it. and I can´t write-open it in perl script.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the file attributes?  When you right-click on the c file, look at the bottom of the 'General' tab, is "Attributes: Read-only" checked?  This will override your DACL security.

Read-only might be checked if you copied the file from a CD-ROM or DVD.